# Determine number of days within a date range across multiple years

Tags: excel

I hope I can explain this properly. I need to calculate occupancy time for a population of migratory animals. Occupancy is defined as the period, in days, between the first and last sighting of an individual in a given year between 1999 and 2015. A sample of the type of sighting data I am dealing with is pasted below. I need to be able to calculate the number of days between sightings within a year and NOT between the first and last sightings or between each sighting. Further, I need a value of "1" if the animal was only seen once in that year, rather than a value of "0". 
So, for example, based on individual 37 in the data below, the results table would look something like

1999 - 0  2000 - 11  2001 - 40  2002 - 2  2003 - 0

- 1999 - 0
- 2000 - 11
- 2001 - 40
- 2002 - 1
- 2003 - 0
- 2004 - 52
- 2005 - 1

...and so on.

I have tried this series of equations but it does not return the right values for the years in which an animal was seen only once and it ignores any years prior to the first year seen.

in cell K2:

=DATE(YEAR(MIN($B$2:$J$2)),1,1)

in cell L2:

=IF(N(K2)=0,"",MAX(MAX(IF($B$2:$J$2=K2,$B$2:$J$2)),0))

in cell M2:

=IF(N(K2)=0,"",IF(MAX($B$2:$J$2)>DATE(YEAR(K2)+1,1,1),DATE(YEAR(K2)+1,1,1),""))

[image]

Comment: You've definitely been here long enough to know you have to show effort.

Comment: look into DATEDIF() it is a hidden formula, but it is there.  Then you want the MIN(IF()) and MAX(IF()).  If you have the latest version of 365 or using the online you would use MINIF() and MAXIF().  The IF portion to limit it to the proper year.

Comment: Is there a hidden turn me into @ScottCraner formula?

Comment: @findwindow Fair enough. I have edited the post to show what I have already tried. Sorry for not including it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

so if more than 1 year between sightings then it should be 0?
and is that more than "365 days a year" or if it is spotted 1 time 1. december and 1 time 1. januar then its still only spotted 1 time pr year...

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Sightings are within a calendar year only.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution using this equation in the cells immediately following the last sighting.

=IF(COUNTIFS($B2:$V2,">="&DATE(BE$1,1,1),$B2:$V2,"<="&DATE(BE$1,12,31))>0,LOOKUP(DATE(BE$1,12,31),$A2:$V2)-INDEX($A2:$V2,MATCH(DATE(BE$1,1,0),$A2:$V2)+1)+1,0)